# How to filter data according to strict match in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

i want to filter data on the fly when data is provided to ng-grid in angular. what i am trying to achieve is that when i filtering 'Nephi' then all the data which contain 'Nephi' with its.

I am providing a plunker link to better understand:

Like if i search 'Nephi' then it should only give me 1 result or exact result(expected result)
1. Nephi

but right now it is giving me:
1. Nephi
2. Nephiss
3. Nephisss

Comment: Plunker link http://plnkr.co/edit/ROACCzIMBpukJimtBQnI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter accepts regex, so using this:

```
var filterText = 'name:^Nephi$';
```

Will work. The regex matches the start of the string (using `^`), the word we want, then the end of the string (using `$`).

Comment: Hi @Mohso, is there a way to show breadcrumbs like if i selected nephi then it should show me "Home / Nephi" similar to this

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a newer version of angular just add :true for an exact match.

```
<div ng-repeat="val in items | filter:{item: '!search'}:true">{{val.item}}</div>
```